# How to access a VUE plugin function from an imported module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I developed a plugin to centralize HTTP calls and need to access its function (`$ap`i) from an imported module in a component.
The following works fine:
**The plugin** (http-transport.js)

```
export default {
    install: function (Vue) { ...
    Vue.prototype.$api = (...)
```

**main.js**

```
import HTTPTransport from './http-transport/http-transport'
Vue.use (HTTPTransport);
```

Usage from any `component.vue`

```
 methods: {
    someMethod() {
       this.$api(...)
}}
```

All the above works.

Now, I have a SFC component that imports a module
**component.vue**

```
import logic from "./LogicService.js";
```

**The question**: how can I call `$api` from a function within `LogicService.js`?

The real case is that LogicService.js imports DataService.js from which I need to call the $api function, but I guess the solution to the question solves this as well.
Thanks so much!
(vue 2.6.11)

Answer (score 2):

there are couple ways to do that.
the most easy way is just import vue and call the function. but for that case you must add the plugin function as global to vue

for example. in http-transport.js

```
export default function (Vue) {
  //add global method or property
  Vue.api= function () {
    // some logic ...
    api();
    
  }
  //add an instance method
  Vue.prototype.$api= function () {
    // some logic ...
    api();
  }
}

function api(){
//code goes here
}
```

and then in your js files just import `Vue` and call `Vue.api()`.

for example in LogicService.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
export default function(){
//call api
  Vue.api();
}
```

the problem with this way is that you can access `Vue.api` only when vue finish installize (most cases that the case so no problem).

a second way you can do that is to write the plugin like that

```
export default function (Vue) {
  //add global method or property
  Vue.api= function () {
    // some logic ...
    api();
    
  }
  //add an instance method
  Vue.prototype.$api= function () {
    // some logic ...
    api();
  }
}

export function api(){
//code goes here
}
```

now the plugin is actually indepent of vue and can work by itself without vue. for example now you can do that in LogicService.js

```
import {api} from './http-transport.js'
api()
```

Comment: Great help, thanks! I finally chose to refactor the plugin into a regular js module